# How to stop server side processing when user clicks browser stop button (ASP.net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I remember I could easily do this in PHP but can't seem to find an answer for ASP.Net. I have a web app that connects to Pop3 server to download emails when a user clicks a button or at set intervals. This process can take a very long time to finish depending on the number of emails to be downloaded. I noticed that when I click the browser stop button the process still continues to download emails preventing the user from navigating to another page. I have tried Response.IsClientConnected property but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Actually php does it by default but you can override it by setting ignore_user_abort(true).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The stop button in the browser will only stop rendering the response. The server however, will keep building the response till it's complete.

Comment: True, you have to move to another page or close your browser to forcefully close the connection (Therefore have Response.IsClientConnected return true)